# How to check if a post belongs to a category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to check if a certain post belongs to a category or belongs to a descendant of a certain category.
Is there a WordPress function for this, or do I need to do it myself?

I should have mentioned that the WP version is 2.7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$post = get_post($id);
$category = $post->$post_category;
cat_is_ancestor_of(($parent_category, $category));
```

For more info see the [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) and [cat is ancestor of](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/cat_is_ancestor_of) references. Also, while somewhat difficult to find [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) is a good place to start for most wp development related things.

Answer (score 12):

For 2.7 or above use `in_category($category, $_post)`